# Guzzle json Boolean issue false is blank

Tags: php, json, guzzle

I have a PHP Twig font-end calling a Python Flask API. API is doing exactly what I presume it should in that the ORM, DB, Objects and Json are all treating Boolean like 0 - False and 1 - True or true/ false in json (python is True False None)

Looking at the sent JSON a field like `{"required": false, "data": "other"` is just that (proper json)

However when the response in PHP Guzzle is parsed like so:

```
$obj= json_decode($gResponse->getBody()->getContents(), TRUE);
```

The field of `obj['required']` is blank or `{"required" => , "other" => "data"}`

`true` apparently gets translated to 1

Is there anyway to make Guzzle follow proper json? json supports Boolean why is Guzzle going through the hassle of converting them?

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($obj['required'])`?

Comment: False is often interpreted as blank, otherwise you'd see `''`. That's fine. If you want the number, try `(int)$obj['required'];`

Comment: Depending on how you output it, it may actual be `false` PHP has a tendency to output falsy values as ... well... nothing.  Print R suffers from this as you can see [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1cf62f5d5511d82c939951016b42c34f3b4af236).  Personally I wouldn't sweat it.

Comment: @ceejayoz interesting `var_dump` has the boolean while `print_r` does not... so it does not appear to be Guzzle as I had thought. Twig must be parsing it differently then...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix seems that you are correct. I was using `print_r` or outputting the variable in Twig which is also blank. However as my other comment shows `var_dump` appears to see a boolean false. Just a bit of a PHP issue then it appears. Odd I have never noticed this before first time not being all in PHP.

Comment: @MaximShubin I will give it to you that would have solved my issue I was not factoring in the cast done my Twig so that was not where I was looking.

Comment: @nerdlyist - `var_export` is specifically made to output syntactically correct arrays.  `print_r` is made to display arrays in a "human" readable way.  `var_dump` is more appropriate to debugging, but harder to read.

Comment: When `true` is cast to string it is `"1"`. When `false` is cast to string it is `""`. Welcome to PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the comments, `var_dump($obj['required'])` shows it equals `false`, as expected.

Twig is going to cast it as a string for output, and `(string)false` results in an empty string `""`. If you want it to output `true` or `false`:

```
{{ $obj['required'] ? 'true' : 'false' }}
```

Comment: This is what I had ended up doing anyway. Seems to be the "expected" behavior so I am not messing anything up!